# Maximum control number of master pages in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

As developers know, SharePoint 2010 master pages can contain maximum 200 controls. I've searched arround a bit, but did not get any information or suggestion about this problem. Anyone faced with this problem before? I call this is a problem, because I need to put more than 200 controls. Do you have any suggestion about how to put 200+ controls in masterpage? Any trick, way, etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked the web.config? There is an entry for the user controls:

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true" DirectFileDependencies="20" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="false">
```

However I would not suggest changing it, because the limit of 200 exists for a reason. Actually a MS employee suggests you should split up your page into multiple smaller pages if you have more than 200 user controls: [Need increase MaxControls value in web.config. Is there a recommended value?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/665ea532-59ee-417e-8650-7d9136ca71e7)